# Securely feeding a program with a password

Tags: security, password, bash-script

After understanding [the problem with using a password in the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78734/why-not-using-passwords-in-command-line), I need to find a way of feeding a program with a password without it being a problem (without the password being recorded somewhere).

I have a bash script that automatically installs an entire LAMP server from source: Apache, FastCGI, PHP & MySQL.
These installations require a password, especially MySQL.

How can I make the script fully automated without revealing the password?

Edit (9 June, 3:55 UTC):
I'm invoking mysql with a password on the command line, via root:

```
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor# PASS=`cat /home/dor/tmpf/pass`
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor# mysql -u root -p"$PASS"
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
```

(PASS="p4ssw0rd" in our case)
And I execute `ps aux | grep mysql` via my regular user (dor), which **doesn't show me the password**!
(Some of) `ps` output is:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      3562  0.0  0.0  34156  2864 pts/0    S+   05:53   0:00 mysql -u root -px xxxxxx
```

How's that possible?

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339/135943, but note **this does not make it safe!**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In regard to your update:

When a process is started it has a dedicated area of memory where arguments are stored and a int which tells how many arguments was passed.

```
MEMORY
argc    2
argv[0] program_name
argv[1] foo
argv[2] bar
```

MySQL check if password was passed on command line by `-p`, and if it was copy it to a new variable that is not visible, then overwrite that region of memory with `x`'es.

In simple terms e.g.:

```
argc 2
argv[1] -p
argv[2] p4ssw0rd

new_var = copy(argv[2]);
argv[2] = "xxxxx";
```

You can find it e.g. in `client/mysqladmin.cc` of the source code:

```
  case 'p':
      ...
      opt_password=my_strdup(argument,MYF(MY_FAE));
      while (*argument) 
          *argument++= 'x';     /* Destroy argument */
```

When `ps` run it reads the memory region of the arguments, (`argv[N]`), and thus it is `xxxx`.

For a very short while the password is visible, but only for a few CPU cycles.

---

You can update the MySQL password using the special `--init-file` option and procedure. [C.5.4.1.2. Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix)

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

---

***Edit:***

As [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) say, you can [`echo`, `printf`](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) or use `here` document from a script.

You can also add this to `.my.cnf` of your home directory or in a (*temporary*) file and use the [`--defaults-extra-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-extra-file) option. *(Believe you have to add that option early on the command line.)* optionally also include user. Also note the **extra** in the option name unless you want to use *only* that file as configuration:

```
[client]
user=foo
password='password!'
```

```
shell> chmod 400 my_tmp.cnf
shell> mysql --defaults-extra-file=my_tmp.conf -...
```

Optionally the `[client]` grouping makes `mysqld` skip the configuration.

One can also use [`MYSQL_PWD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html) environment variable, but that should *never* be used as you can list environment, in many `ps` implementations by `ps -e`, in the `/proc/<PID>/environ` file on Linux etc.

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/<PID>/environ
```

More on the topic [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

You might also want to have a look at the [MySQL Configuration Utility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) which enables you to store password in a encrypted file in your home directory – `.mylogin.cnf`.

Comment: Is there a way to change a token in the `mysql-init` file with the password that is stored in a bash variable? (without being revealed)

Comment: @Dor Something like `echo 'password=p4ssw0rd' >>mysql.cnf` is safe, because `echo` is a built-in, so the password doesn't appear on the command line of any process. A here document is also safe.

Answer (score 5):

The typical solution is to read the password from a file or from standard input (or from another file descriptor which would have to be passed as a parameter).

Answer (score 4):

Some programs (command line `ftp` for example) read passwords from `/dev/tty`, the per-process special file that represents the process' controlling TTY. This lets the program not echo the password back to the screen, and to have a little more assurance about where the password comes from.

```
#!/bin/bash

stty -F /dev/tty -echo 
read PASSWORD < /dev/tty

echo $PASSWORD
```