# Open output of a command using libreoffice

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, libreoffice

I am running certain commands in a loop and would like to open its output in libreoffice (calc), without storing it.

This is what I have tried:

```
libreoffice --calc <(process m n)
libreoffice --calc < $(process m n)
process m n | libreoffice --calc
```

I am getting an error in the first two, whereas for the third one, it opens libreoffice, but no file!

However if I save the output of `process` to a file `f` and open `libreoffice f`, it works!

Is it that I am doing something wrong, or its a limitation of libreoffice? My question is is there any way to avoid local storage?

Comment: Related, covers the same question for OpenOffice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91088/is-it-possible-to-feed-open-office-via-stdin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a limitation / missing feature (?) in LibreOffice.

What I did, with `test.csv` being a valid CSV file :

- `libreoffice --calc test.csv` : opens `test.csv` in "Calc" as expected
- `cat test.csv | libreoffice --calc` : starts "Calc" with a blank spreadsheet

`man libreoffice` states :

> --calc Starts with a new Calc document.

It doesn't mention reading from standard input.

Similar information here : [Is it possible to feed Open Office via STDIN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91088/is-it-possible-to-feed-open-office-via-stdin)

Suggestions to avoid local storage :

- since commands building the data file are run in a loop, always write into the very same file. You'll avoid filling storage with temporary data
- write into temporary storage areas such as `/tmp`
- write into `tmpfs` filesystems (`mount | grep tmpfs` to list those. Typically `/dev/shm`)

Comment: Does this really answer the question raised by the OP?