# How to pass password to mysql command line

Tags: password, mysql, stdin

I have MySQL password saved on a file `foo.php`, for example `P455w0rd`, when I try to use it:

```
$ cat foo.php | grep '$dbpwd=' | cut -d '"' -f 2 | mysql -U root -p mydb -h friendserver
Enter password: (holds)

$ echo P455w0rd | mysql -u root -p mydb -h friendserver
Enter password: (holds)
```

Both option still ask for password, what's the correct way to send password from `stdin`?

Comment: must be no blank between `-p` and your password.

Comment: mysql doesn't read the password from stdin, I wasn't able to figure it what it does read it from.

Comment: The proper answer is **don't put your passwords on the command line where anyone with access to `/proc` can trivially read them as long as the program is running**. That's what a `~/.my.cnf` is for, properly chmod'ed to 0600

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have to be very careful how you pass passwords to command lines as, if you're not careful, you'll end up leaving it open to sniffing using tools such as `ps`.

---

The safest way to do this would be to create a new config file and pass it to `mysql` using either the `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` command line option.

The difference between the two is that the latter is read in addition to the default config files whereas with the former, only the one file passed as the argument is used.

Your additional configuration file should contain something similar to:

```
[client]
user=foo
password=P@55w0rd
```

Make sure that you secure this file.

Then run:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=<path to the new config file> [all my other options]
```

Comment: MySQL will modify its `argv` to overwrite the parameters given to the `-p` flag. At least that's what's concluded here, together with other relevant info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78757/securely-feeding-a-program-with-a-password

Comment: This is the best solution, as it provides a measure of security. You need to chmod go-rwx, and make sure this argument preceeds all other arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, but as per comments on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339/135943, that **does not** mean it's safe!

Comment: Might be worth adding a note about `--login-path` now that it's supported. It's not much better than this, but it is slightly less plain-text (even though the barrier to converting the contents to plaintext is low).

Comment: Set MYSQL_PWD in the environment (`export MYSQL_PWD=muhpassword`) and execute your command without the `-p`. See [MySQL Program Environment Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html). In spite of the manual's [dire warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html), this is [rather safe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20282/is-passing-sensitive-data-through-the-process-environment-secure). Unless you start weird warez in the same shell later. So we run: `MYSQL_PWD=$(cat foo.php etc) mysql -u foouser -h barhost`

Comment: The --defaults-extra-file must be the first option when executing the mentioned command. For me, it didn't work otherwise.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer this should be an answer on its own.

Comment: `defaults-extra-file` didn't worked for me, but `defaults-file` worked ok. Thx, solved my problem (not wanting to put secrets in cmd).

Answer (score 102):

The `mysql` client utility can take a password on the command line with either the `-p` or `--password=` options.

If you use `-p`, there must not be any blank space after the option letter:

```
$ mysql -pmypassword
```

I prefer the long options in scripts as they are self-documenting:

```
mysql --password=mypassword --user=me --host=etc
```

Comment: This is insecure because any user could view the password - either directly via `/proc/$pid/cmdline` or via the `ps` command. It's true that mysql overwrites the password in argv during startup but there is always a time window where another user could observe the password. Also, on some systems the argv overwriting might not work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that there must not be any blank space after the option letter. Saved my day.

Comment: Of course this is insecure, but most people are doing something like this in a build process that will be deleted shortly afterwards...

Comment: List of running processes might be captured by machine monitoring tools and appear then in log files. A short running process is a bad excuse.

Comment: Just be a 'real person' and enter the password when prompted rather than sharing it with anyone, including your mother.

Answer (score 12):

create a file ~/.my.cnf, make it only accessible by yourself, permission 600.

```
   [client]
   user=myuser
   password=mypassword
```

Then you don't need type password any more.

```
   bash$ mysql -u myuser mydatabase
   mysql>
```

Comment: Using `mysql_config_editor` (an official MySQL tool which stores the credentials obfuscated in ~/.mylogin.cnf`) is slightly more secure (or less insecure).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use a nifty Linux trick...

`/dev/stdin` can be used as a file resource for `--defaults-file` like so:

`echo -e "[client]\nuser=xxx\npassword=xxx" | mysql --defaults-file=/dev/stdin -e 'select user()' <database_name>`

You can usually use `-` instead of `/dev/stdin`, but it's a convention that a lot of programs (including `mysql`) do not honour.

A little more about the `/dev/stdin` file resource:

```
$ ls -la /dev/stdin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun 19 08:35 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
```

This way you can also check **empty password situations**

Comment: you should use `password` instead of `pass` to not see the following error: 
`Info: Using unique option prefix 'pass' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'password' instead.`

Comment: What's with the `'select user()` bit? I couldn't get this to work. It just outputs `user()`.

Comment: This is probably the safest answer, as you won't need to write the credentials to file. You could probably also use process substitution instead of stdin, but the idea is the same. Not sure if that makes a difference to whether a different process can read from the file descriptor, but perhaps someone can enlighten us on that.

Comment: this one is geeky ❤️, you deserve a +1

Answer (score 5):

As @maxschlepzig said in a comment,

> Note that there is the MYSQL_PWD environment variable which is read by mysql if you don't specify -p.

So in bash:

```
read -s -p "Enter the mysql password for $DBUSER @ $DBNAME: " DBPASS 
export MYSQL_PWD="$DBPASS" 
mysqldump -u $DBUSER $DBNAME > dump.sql

# once you are done
export MYSQL_PWD=""
```

Comment: From [the MySQL 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) (below the table): "Use of `MYSQL_PWD` to specify a MySQL password must be considered extremely insecure and should not be used. [...] `MYSQL_PWD` is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL."

Answer (score -2):

If you want to start `mysql` with a password provided you have to fetch the password in a variable first:

```
MYSQLPASS=`cat foo.php | grep '$dbpwd=' | cut -d '"' -f 2`
```

Then you can start your `mysql` command with:

```
mysql -U root -p ${MYSQLPASS} mydb -h friendserver
```

Comment: This also [jeopardizes your password security](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205180/how-to-pass-password-to-mysql-command-line#comment980999_339533). Note that there is the `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable which is read by `mysql` if you don't specify `-p`. And under Linux this is a secure method because the environment of a user cannot be read by other unprivilleged users - in contrast to the argument vector.

Comment: You also can't trust environment variables to be secure, but it's better than providing it as an argument. Moreover, [use of `MYSQL_PWD` is deprecated from MySQL 8.0 forward](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html).