# Split MySQL query into an [executional part] and a [MySQL command part]

Tags: bash, mysql

Following

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -D database -s -N -e "SELECT id FROM myTable"
```

with special password and database is working fine.

I want to split the code into two parts:

1. *Executional* part:

   `mysqlE=mysql -u root -ppassword -D database -s -N -e`

and

2. MySQL command part:

   `query="SELECT id FROM myTable"`

to execute it with something similar like:

```
mysqlE query
```

How can I do this?

Comment: passing a password on the command line is a bad idea as it can easily be viewed from /proc or by running `ps`.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205184/7696 for a better alternative.  Remember to `chmod 600` the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it already for a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqlE="mysql -u root -ppassword -D database -s -N -e"
query="SELECT id FROM myTable"
$mysqlE "$query"
```

Another way is to put the mysql command in a function (put it in ~/.bashrc for instance)

```
function mysqlE()
{
    mysql -u root -ppassword -D database -s -N -e "$@"
}
```

from a new shell or `source ~/.bashrc` use

```
mysqlE "$query"
```