# Pass output from metadata call to MySQL

Tags: shell-script, mysql

Reference: [How to pass password to mysql command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205180/how-to-pass-password-to-mysql-command-line)

I want to grab returned metadata from an AWS EC2 instance and set a new mysql password based on this data.

I need assistance with the script which will run as first boot.

```
#!/bin/bash  
output=$(ec2metadata --instance-id); Used for storing EC2 ID.   

mysql -u root -pOldPassword  
UPDATE mysql.user
```

Now pass instance-id and use it to set a new password for mysql root.

```
SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('$output'), password_expired = 'N'
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

EXIT
```

Comment: do you just need something like: `iid=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have gotten that far  thanks; however, my issue remains how to pass that back MySQL. Right now, I have it `output=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)` then I use a `my.cnf` to set MySQL credentials to allow bash: `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD($output),` but it fails here as I don't know the correct syntax for MySQL to accept a bash variable.

Comment: could you edit your post with the current situation? comments are hard to keep track of / read.

Comment: @Jeff, updated for post for clarity. Logic is correct. I omitted the requirement to use my.cnf. The issue appears to be how the mysql line is formatted with quotes. I was able to test a working solution, and will post the solution when I can confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bash do not expand variables in single quotes. Apart from that, you can run multiple SQL queries, or a single one if you prefer to, by using the **`<<EOF...EOF`** construction. The code below worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                 

newpass="newPassword"

mysql -u root -poldPassword <<EOF                                                                                                                  
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD("$newpass") WHERE User='root';                                                                      
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;                                                                                                                           
QUIT                                                                                                                                        
EOF
```

You may run the properly `UPDATE` command according to your MySQL version. I was using *5.6.35*. In case you are running MySQL *5.7* only, use the following `UPDATE` query instead of that shown above:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("$newpass") WHERE User='root';
```

You can find more information in the MySQL official docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html