# How to avoid password prompt with rsync (and without using public keys)?

Tags: ssh, rsync, password

I need to execute `rsync`, without it prompting me for password.

I've seen in `rsync` manpage that it doesn't allow specifying the password as command line argument.
But I noticed that it allows specifying the password via the variable `RSYNC_PASSWORD`.

So I've tried exporting the variable, but `rsync` keeps asking me for password.

```
export RSYNC_PASSWORD="abcdef"
rsync root@1.2.3.4:/abc /def
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Please consider:*

- I understand that this is a **bad idea from security aspect**
- I must use only `rsync`, can't use other software
- I can't use key-based authentication
- I've already read many SE question, e.g.:
  [how-to-pass-password-for-rsync-ssh-command @ stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299951/how-to-pass-password-for-rsync-ssh-command)
  [rsync-cron-job-with-a-password @ superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/325715/rsync-cron-job-with-a-password)
  [how-to-setup-rsync-without-password-with-ssh-on-unix-linux @ superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/555799/how-to-setup-rsync-without-password-with-ssh-on-unix-linux)

In other words, I need to have the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` approach working! :-)

Comment: have you enable rsync daemon on remote server ?

Comment: Not always an option, but one can use the `mirror` option with `lftp` to do this over SFTP. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153408/282432)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This password environment variable appears only to be used when using the rsync protocol:

```
rsync rsync://username@1.2.3.4:/abc /def
```

For this to work, you need to run rsync as a daemon as well (`--daemon` option), which is often done using `inetd.conf`.

When using this protocol, `abc` should correspond to a target defined in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`. The user name should be present in a [`auth users`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.5#auth_users) line for this target, and a password file should be specified with the [`secrets file`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.5#secrets_file) option.

It is this secrets file that contains mappings between user names and passwords in the following format:

```
username:password
```

And it is this password that you can specify using the [RSYNC_PASSWORD](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#RSYNC_PASSWORD) environment variable.

Comment: a quicky way to run an rsync server is with [https://s3.amazonaws.com/skaperen/rsend](http://web.archive.org/web/20151013142515/https://s3.amazonaws.com/skaperen/rsend)

Answer (score 115):

If the `rsync` daemon isn't running on the target machine, and you don't care about exposing passwords to everyone on the local machine ([Why shouldn't someone use passwords in the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78734/why-shouldnt-someone-use-passwords-in-the-command-line)),  you can use `sshpass`:

```
 sshpass -p "password" rsync root@1.2.3.4:/abc /def
```

Note the space at the start of the command, in the `bash` shell this will stop the command (and the password) from being stored in the history. I don't recommend using the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` variable unless absolutely necessary (as per a previous edit to this answer), I recommend suppressing history storage or at least clearing history after. In addition, you can use `tput reset` to clear your terminal history.

Comment: Why would you suggest adding password clear text on a command, that's bad linux admin 101.

Comment: Super handy.. been searching for an approach to this for a while. Thank you.

Comment: While this is bad to add the password as clear text, this is currently the only reasonably simple way to this.

Comment: you can always do something like this: `sshpass -p $(cat passFile) ..` to hide clear pass in bash history,, and chmod 400 on passFile to secure it

Comment: Best answer right here. Achieves what one should be able to achieve with only rsync.

Comment: I know that this is old, but for the sake of newer readers, **please** quote the password — passwords can contain special characters and spaces. `-p "$RSYNC_PASSWORD"`

Comment: @PaddyLandau, I edited the answer. I don't actually recommend using the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` variable. But if it is used then, yes I agree it should be quoted.

Comment: One might also consider `sshpass -f passFile`, it interprets first line of the file as password

Comment: Not a big deal if the target account has minimal access restriction just to a folder of backups

Comment: A better way to solve the problem stated in OP, than the (also good) direct answer provided earlier.

Answer (score 21):

Very useful for scripting is to use [`--password-file`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--password-file) command line option.

- Create empty file called rsync_pass
- write in password to this file (nothing more)
- `chmod 600 rsync_pass`
- `rsync $args --password-file=rsync_pass user@rsynchost::/share localdirectory`

This can be used for scripting and allows to be more secure that just exporting password to system variable.

Comment: Note to reader: this also requires an rsync daemon running on the server. I really was hoping that ssh keys would be sufficient for passwordless rsync.

Comment: IMHO this is the only correct way to do it if one doesn't want to use ssh.

Comment: You can use SSH keys. I have done this on my systems. You put the authorized key in the .ssh folder on the side you are trying to ssh to. In my case it is /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and on the side running the rsync command use the -e parameter to specify the ssh settings. In my case it is  -e "ssh -i /path/to/ssh-key" for example.

Comment: The main point was using rsyncd directly, thus ssh key doesn't play a role. It was stated in question 'without using public key authentication'

Answer (score 18):

You can use standard ssh identities to do passwordless login.   This is handled by default if you have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or the like, but you can also hardcode your own path to the private key of an authorized keypair.

This allows batching/scripting without exposing passwords, and the public key can be remove from the target server if the private key is ever compromised.

```
rsync -e"ssh -i /path/to/privateKey" -avR $sourcedir ${ruser}@${rhost}:~/${rdir}/
```

You can also add arguments like `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` to not force remote host key verification.  !Caution - that opens up man in the middle attacks and is general bad practice!

Comment: This is especially useful if you're using the new Bash shell for Windows 10. I was wondering why rsync wasn't working passwordlessly. I realized it was using the `~/.ssh` folder inside the shell (where rsync lives). Once I used -e to point to the key inside `/mnt/c/Users/MyUsername/.ssh`, it worked as expected. (Thanks. :D)

Comment: While helpful in general for promptless access, the original question explicitly asked about *not* using key-based auth.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be an evergreen topic. Therefore I would like to propose the solution which worked best for me on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

My goal was to create a backup on a 1blu cloud drive, which did not allow SSH key login.

1. First, I created the file `~/.rsync_pass` and wrote the password of the SSH user into it.
2. Then I used the `sshpass` command with parameter `-f` to read the password from this file and to pass it to rsync.

```
sshpass -f ~/.rsync_pass rsync -av /var/www/folder/ user@example.com:/backup
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the answer I looked for.
I wished to retrieve backups from VM containing Sangoma FreePBX and Asterisk. But that VM is running using limited resources, thus it was not very wise to keep rsyncD running. Using sshpass and the credentials file does the job as intended.

Answer (score 1):

For rsyncd protocol, use process substitution for the option `--password-file=FILE`

```bsh
rsync --password-file=<(echo "1233456") root@1.2.3.4::abc /def
```

Comment: Hm, idk if I'm doing something wrong, but I couldn't get that to work. `Path '1233456' does not exist`. I'm assuming the string is intended to be the password anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my script inspired by the comments in this post, so I'll post it here as another source of inspiration. My requirements were, no rsyncd on remote, password login, no exposure of password in history or command line. That's actually not very difficult:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=mymachine.mydomain.com
USER=fms
LOCAL=/home/fms/Progetti/MyProject/src

read -s -p "Password for $USER@$HOST: " SSHPASS
echo

sshpass -e rsync -i -r --checksum --delete --chown=nginx:nginx -e "ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password" $LOCAL/lavori_senato $USER@$HOST:/var/www/drupal/test/web/modules/custom
```

I needed to alter the default configuration of my ssh so that it wouldn't try public-key first. The `echo` after `read` is just a touch of formatting, since using `-s` even the end of line is not printed, and the output of rsync overlapped with the password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was as simple as ensuring that keys are added to the agent after first successful connection:

In my `~/.ssh/config`, I have the following entry:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent=yes
```

This ensures that for all hosts, the key is added to the agent after initial connect.

With this enabled, I no longer saw discrepancies between normal ssh and when rsync does its ssh

Answer (score 0):

The only safe and feasible solution that I found over time consists of:

1. Generate a new ssh key specifically for passwordless backups only. Do not use a passphrase with it;
2. Upload it to the server as your normal ssh `user`. Do not create another user for it, or upload it as `www-data` as `www-data` must not be able to login to the system;
3. Change that uploaded key in `authorized_keys` to run a bash script rather than provide the user with a terminal on ssh login. An example would be to replace

   ```
   ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza......k1y0=
   ```

   with something like this

   ```
   command="script.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza......k1y0=
   ```
4. In `script.sh`, you would have something like this:

   ```
     if [[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == "rsync --server --sender -vlDtre.iLsfxCIvu /home/server/files ." ]] 
     then
          $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
     fi
   ```

   where "`rsync --server --sender -vlDtre.iLsfxCIvu /home/server/files .`" is an ssh digest you get from your server when you try to unsuccessfully login with

   ```
   rsync -av -e "ssh -i rsync_key" user@$7.7.7.7:/home/server/files /home/user
   ```

   Upon this unsuccessful login, the value of the digest (i.e. its string value) will be recorded in `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`;
5. **Things to consider**: if you are backing up any webroot files which the standard ssh `user` does not have access to without sudo, add that `user` to group `www-data`
6. **Things to consider**: `www-data` user will need to have maximally restrictive configuration. Ideally we would want something like this:

   ```
    www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
   ```

   which is achievable by running

   ```
     sudo usermod -d /nonexistent $wwwuser -s /usr/sbin/nologin
   ```
7. Now you can ssh to the server to run a passwordless rsync backup

   ```
   rsync -av -e "ssh -i rsync_key" user@$7.7.7.7:/home/server/files /home/user
   ```