# multiple rsync commands without prompting the password multiple times

Tags: rsync

I am writing a bash script to `rsync` multiple files from a remote host into my personal computer.

What I wrote so far works, one `rsync` command after the other (three in total), though I have to input my ssh password after each execution of `rsync`

```
#!/bin/bash
# create the command line argument, that will be PASSED when calling the script
while getopts r: option
do
case "${option}"
in
r) RUNNAME=${OPTARG};;
esac
done

# create the directory on the Toshiba hard Drive
mkdir -p /media/user/TOSHIBA\ EXT/novaseq/$RUNNAME/InterOp

mkdir -p /media/user/TOSHIBA\ EXT/novaseq/$RUNNAME/Unaligned/Stats

# rsync the files into the "base directory"
# the files that have to be rsynced have the extension .csv, .txt and .xml
rsync -avzh user@remote-host:/nexusb/Novaseq/$RUNNAME/*.* /media/user/TOSHIBA\ EXT/novaseq/$RUNNAME/ && rsync -avzh user@remote-host:/nexusb/Novaseq/$RUNNAME/InterOp/*.bin /media/user/TOSHIBA\ EXT/novaseq/$RUNNAME/InterOp && rsync -avzh user@remote-host:/nexusb/Novaseq/$RUNNAME/Unaligned/Stats/*.* /media/user/TOSHIBA\ EXT/novaseq/$RUNNAME/Unaligned/Stats
```

Is there a way to call the three `rsync`commands while inputting the ssh password only **once** instead of thrice?

Comment: Related: [what's the purpose of ssh-agent?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/72552)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111526/how-can-i-rsync-without-prompt-for-password-without-using-public-key-authentica?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As @Kusalananda suggested, use a ssh-agent. As you already login via ssh, simply instantiating a ssh-agent piror to executing the script should work fine.

```bsh
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

You can add multiple ssh keys to the same ssh-agent. `ssh-add` adds the one located in the default location. In case your public / private key pair are not located at the default location, add them to the ssh-add command.

It is also possible to start a ssh-agent when logging in if you use it outside of this script.

edit:
I guess terminating the ssh-agent after the script terminates on the remote server is a good idea, esp. if someone else has got root access it is possible to read out your password. In case you want to have a  solution that is completely secure, check out [this article](http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents).